# Custom related list Lightning component for CaseHistory

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I'm new to saleforce, I want to make a custom case history component using the CaseHistory object, I do the following SOQL

```
List <CaseHistory> caseHist = [SELECT Id,
                 Field,
                 CreatedBy.Name,
                     OldValue,
                 NewValue,
                CreatedDate
                 FROM CaseHistory WHERE CaseId =: caseId ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 3];
```

I have three problems:

1. the field I need the label not the name api
2. update the component when making any changes (as it is a history component, Case (parent) when making modifications to the case when saving it should be displayed in the case history component (child) since they are on the same page)
3. there are changes that are made and keeps two records the id of another object and the name

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get the field names:

```
String type= 'MyCustomObject__c';  // Say,this is my object

Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    Schema.SObjectType leadSchema = schemaMap.get(type);
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = leadSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) {  
        String mylabel;
          //It provides to get the object fields label.
         mylabel = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel();
   }
```

As for your other two issues, can I have some more context/info, please!